# Refresh cache triggered by changes in database is it possible?

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

In my application I'm using Spring, Hibernate and EHCache. Problem is that database is being modifiy by another application.

Is it possible, is there is any implemented solution to refresh cache based on some database changes? I can use some additional column for versioning etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache does not support such a scenario out of the box. Write-through is when changes flow the other way: your application updates the cache and in the background the cache pushes the updates to the database.

In order to push database updates to your application, you will have to come up with your own solution. The ideal way is to not have two different applications hitting the same data but instead have one of the two applications go through the other, so that a single application owns this set of data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is know as `Read-Write Through` Caching. EhCache supports it.

From EhCache Documentation:

> Write-through caching is a caching pattern where writes to the cache
>   cause writes to an underlying resource. The cache acts as a facade to
>   the underlying resource. With this pattern, it often makes sense to
>   read through the cache too. Write-behind caching uses the same client
>   API; however, the write happens asynchronously. Ehcache-2.0 introduced
>   write-through and write-behind caching. While file systems or a
>   web-service clients can underlie the facade of a write-through cache,
>   the most common underlying resource is a database.

Here is a detailed article:
http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/write-through-caching.html#write-through-and-write-behind-caching-with-the-cachewriter-

Answer (score 0):

Used below solution to refresh cache after each database save

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = {"my-cache"}, allEntries = true)
public MyObject save(MyObject object) {
    MyObject myObject = myRepo.save(object);
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> config.loadData());
    return myObject;
}
```